# Array of objects json stringify and decode - cant access the data

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

Im building an array of objects which i then stringify and send with ajax, the problem is im not able to loop through the result and get the needed data.

The whole script `doit.php` is crashing when i run the foreach loop but if i just echo a random string it will alert and console log that string.

index.php

```
<script>
    function ajax(url, parameters, method, form = false, callback = false) {
        var ajax_http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var ajax_parameters;

        ajax_http.open(method, url, true);
        if (form === false) {
            ajax_parameters = parameters;
            ajax_http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        } else {
            ajax_parameters = new FormData(form);
        }
        ajax_http.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajax_http.readyState === 4 && ajax_http.status === 200) {
                if (callback) {
                    callback(ajax_http.responseText);
                } else {
                    return ajax_http.responseText;
                }
            }
        };
        ajax_http.send(ajax_parameters ? ajax_parameters : null);
    }

    var data = [];

    var obj = {id: 1, name: "christian"};
    data.push(obj);

    var obj = {id: 2, name: "frej"};
    data.push(obj);

    console.log(data);
    data = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(data);


    ajax("doit.php", "data=" + data, "POST", false, function (results) {

        alert(results);
        console.log(results);
    });

</script>
```

doit.php

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);

$str = "";
foreach($data as $person){
    $str .= $person["name"];
}

echo "str = " . $str;
```

Comment: What is this $coin var??? Nonsense here

Comment: Why the downvote? it was from the original project... i changed it to person if that makes better sence :)

Comment: Where exactly is the very first point of failure?

Comment: I get a crash when i run the foreach, but im not sure at all how to retrieve this data.

Comment: What errors are in your log?  If `person[0]` contains `['id'=>1,'name'=>'christian']` then you can't simply concatenate the subarray to a string.  Is that your problem?  It looks like you are trying to put a square peg in a round hole (array into a string).

Comment: Do `var_dump()` or `print_r()` of your $person inside the loop.

Comment: What is your expected output?  Do you want `christianfrej`?  (because it almost looks like that _might_ be your intent)

Comment: Person[0] won't work, you are iterating over items so you access array properties directly (that's the purpose of the loop). Please do a minimum of debug before posting here... Because for the last 30 minutes we still don't understand what your problem

Comment: I want to store lets say the data in variables inside the loop and then query them to the database

Comment: stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => christian
)
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 2
    [name] => frej
)

Comment: Since you are not decoding with `true` access the objects in php using `$person->name`

Comment: Pierre your assuming stuff here, it makes me a little mad honestly. I havent done anything else for the past 5 hours than trying to watch tutorials, debug, trying different things but i just cant get it to work.
Setup testing files here at the end to try a more simple approach.

The person[0] was a trial and error effort from my side of things.

Comment: Thanks mickmackusa that actually worked :) you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to access a single column of data and glue the objects/elements together, you don't need to loop and use concatenation.

I think `array_column()` and `implode()` will look cleaner...

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/W7ngt))

```
$data=[(object)['id'=>1,'name'=>'christian'],(object)['id'=>2,'name'=>'frej']];

echo implode(', ',array_column((array)$data,'name'));
//                             ^^^^^^^- cast as array if you are not using json_decode($data,true);
```

Output:

```
christian, frej
```

---

If you use `$data = json_decode($_POST['data'],true);` (and I recommend it) then you can write:

```
echo implode(', ',array_column($data,'name'));
```

Comment: Thanks this clarified alot of things for me